# Trying to echo variable inside of private static array from include

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to store password sensitive information in a seperate .php file.  I am able to include that file on another php file (we will call it php2.php)

The problem is, the code I'm attempting to use on php1.php does not want to echo the variable that has been designated in the php2.php page.  Anywhere outside the array I can echo a variable and it will display it with no issue.  I'm sure it's just a syntax error as I am beginning to learn PHP.

Any help is appreciated!  Thank you for looking.

Edit: Update!

Here is full page of code I'm trying to work with, getting an error on line 64 now.

```
    <?php

        require_once 'login.php';


        // dota2 api key (you can get_info it here - http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey)
        $APIkey;

        //The language to retrieve results in (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1 for the language codes (first two characters) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes for the country codes (last two characters))
        define ('LANGUAGE', 'en_us');

        error_reporting(0);

        set_time_limit(0);

        /**
         * Basic class with system's configuration data
         */
        class LoginInfo {
            /**
             * Configuration data
             * @access private
             * @static
             * @var array
             */

                private static $_data = array(
                    'APIkey'  => '',
                    'db_user' => '',
                    'db_pass' => '',
                    'db_host' => '',
                    'db_name' => '',
                    'db_table_prefix' => ''
                );

                public static function SetVar ($APIkey, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbhost, $dbname, $Prefix = null){
                    self:: $_data['APIkey']  = $APIkey;
                    self:: $_data['db_user'] = $dbuser;
                    self:: $_data['db_pass'] = $dbpass;
                    self:: $_data['db_host'] = $dbhost;
                    self:: $_data['db_name'] = $dbname;
                    if ($Prefix === null){
                        self::$_data['db_table_prefix'] = '';
                    }else{
                        self::$_data['db_table_prefix'] = $Prefix;
                    }
                }

                public static function GetInfo(){
                    return self::$_data;
                }


            /**
             * Private construct to avoid object initializing
             * @access private
             */
            private function __construct() {}
            public static function init() {
                self::$_data['base_path'] = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'includes';
                $db = db::obtain(echo LoginInfo::GetInfo()['db_user'], echo LoginInfo::GetInfo()['db_pass'], echo LoginInfo::GetInfo()['db_host'], echo LoginInfo::GetInfo()['db_name'], echo LoginInfo::GetInfo()['db_user']);
                if (!$db->connect_pdo()) {
                    die();
                };
            }
            /**
             * Get configuration parameter by key
             * @param string $key data-array key
             * @return null
             */
            public static function get($key) {
                if(isset(self::$_data[$key])) {
                    return self::$_data[$key];
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        config::init();

        function __autoload($class) {
            scan(config::get('base_path'), $class);
        }

        function scan($path = '.', $class) {
            $ignore = array('.', '..');
            $dh = opendir($path);
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($dh))){
                if(!in_array($file, $ignore)) {
                    if(is_dir($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)) {
                        scan($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file, $class);
                    }
                    else {
                        if ($file === 'class.'.$class.'.php') {
                            require_once($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Ohh, I understood your question now.

Comment: I'm sure that the <?php echo $variable ?> is the issue, and I've tried using just echo $variable, but inside the '' it dislikes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your approach: *member properties of objects do not accept expressions as default values*.

What I mean is:

```
<?php
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

class Clazz {
    public $foo = $bar;
    static private $_data = array(
        'foo' => $foo,
        'bar' => $bar
    );
}
```

Try this code [here](http://phpfiddle.org/) and see for yourself. All declarations are syntax errors with an `unexpected T_VARIABLE`.

Your case needs a different approach, something like an initialization method or a singleton which sets up `$_data` in its constructor.

Examples:

```
<?php
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

class Clazz {
    public $foo = '';

    static private $_data = array(
        'foo' => '',
        'bar' => ''
    );
    static private $_ininiated = false;

    static public function init( ) {
        if( !self::$_initiated ) {
            self::$_data = array(
                'foo' => $foo,
                'bar' => $bar
            );
            self::$_initiated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Singleton example:

```
<?php
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

class Clazz {

    static private $instance = null;

    private $_data = array();

    private function __construct( ) {
        $this->_data = array(
            'foo' => $foo,
            'bar' => $bar
        );
    }

    public function getData( $name ) {
        return isset($this->data[$name]) ? $this->data[$name] : null;
    }


    static public function getInstance( ) {
        if( self::$instance == null ) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

}

echo Clazz::getInstance()->getData('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this in a class (hence the allowance of `private static`

```
   class Random {
    private static $_Data = array(
        'db_user' => '',
        'db_pass' => '',
        'db_host' => '',
        'db_name' => '',
        'db_table_prefix' => ''
    );

    public static function SetVar ($Host,$User,$Pass,$DB,$Prefix = null){
        self::$_Data['db_user'] = $User;
        self::$_Data['db_pass'] = $Pass;
        self::$_Data['db_host'] = $Host;
        self::$_Data['db_name'] = $DB;
        if ($Prefix === null){
            self::$_Data['db_table_prefix'] = '';
        }else{
            self::$_Data['db_table_prefix'] = $Prefix;
        }

    }

    public static function GetInfo(){
        return self::$_Data;
    }

}
```

Then call as following:

```
Random::SetVar("Test","Test","Test","Test");
print_r(Random::GetInfo());
```

Or even to access:

```
   echo Random::GetInfo()['db_user'];
```

But if your using an older version of PHP which doesn't support the above call type:

```
 $Var = Random::GetInfo();
 echo $Var['db_user'];
```

Comment: Thank you, getting an error now at a different line (64).  It does not like using (echo .....).  Here is full code from page...

It will not let me post code into comment, please look at originally question where I have pasted it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tandar If your still having this issue, I apologize for not replying until now. Let me know if your still stuck and i'm at your service

Comment: Hi! Yeah that's ok, I know everyone has their own stuff to do :)  I have continued to tinker with it, but have not made much progress, any more help would be appreciated.  I've considered starting over and using a different method even.

Comment: @Tandar What is it your stuck on? Update your question as much as possible

Comment: @Daryll It dislikes me trying to use the echo for the class that is set up to pull in the sensitive data.  echo LoginInfo::GetInfo()['dbuser'] to be more precise

Comment: @Tandar Then you should use the second example that I have posted